# Unit Test warning when migrating from 1.5 to 1.7

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-1.5, django-1.7

I have migrated my project from Django 1.5.1 to 1.7.

I have removed South from the installed apps. But when I execute the `runserver` command, I am getting the following warning, even though I have not written any unit test in the project.

> Some project unittests may not execute as expected. HINT: Django 1.6
>   introduced a new default test runner. It looks like this project was
>   generated using Django 1.5 or earlier. You should ensure your tests
>   are all running & behaving as expected. See
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/#new-test-runner
>   for more information.

How can I remove this warning message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this into your `settings.py`:

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
```